# Adobe AIR: Load data asynchronously from iFrame (iOS-p

Tags: ios, asynchronous, air

We have an Adobe AIR Mobile-Application that displays a webpage (let's call it run.html), which contains an iFrame. The run.html-page is a local page and is located in the application storage directory.
After loading run.html, the src-Attribute of the iFrame is set to a value, which makes the iFrame load another page (let's call it content.html), which is located in the same folder as run.html

content.html now tries to asynchronously load a JSON-file via Javascript, which works well on Android devices, but on iOS devices this does not seem to work.

This is strange since we assumed that the pages are rendered by AIR and should follow the same policies regardless of the device.

So why does it work in Android, but not on iOS? And why doesn't it work on iOS?

We have spent countless hours to no avail, so we would be really thankful for any support on this...